# Detecting email in gmail inbox with chrome extention

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension to interact with an email inside gmail inbox. I want to detect if an email of gmail inbox is opened on chrome browser.

Currently what I'm doing is checking if the prefix of url is **mail.google.com/mail** and if the url contains the term **inbox** (assuming url always will be something like **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/14f045t34g66rc02**). But I recently found that the term **inbox** is not always there when user opens an email inside gmail inbox. For an example if user has custom labels, that label goes to url instead of the term **inbox**. Also if user searches before opening the email the word **search** goes to the url instead of the term **inbox**.

Is there a standard way to do this? Or any stable way?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that I have used to identify if the gmail page is email content is to look for the reply icon. Reply icon is a img tag with background property set to png sprite with -711px

> no-repeat url(//ssl.gstatic.com/mail/sprites/general-38d583f1fd064eadd1975a8bdef3ef93.png) 0 -711px

you can use the jquery css selector like below given pseudo code

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var backgroundValue = $(this).css('background');
    if(backgroundValue.indexOf('//ssl.gstatic.com/mail/sprites/general-38d583f1fd064eadd1975a8bdef3ef93.png') > -1 && backgroundValue.indexOf('-711px') > -1) {
        //this is reply button, so page is email content
        break;
    }
});
```